# How to decrypt the system drive and disable BitLocker in Windows 11 Home?

Tags: backup, encryption, windows-11, bitlocker

So before I install Linux on a laptop I'd want to backup the whole shebang. The laptop is running a fresh OEM install of a Windows 11 Home. I don't have as large drive as the source SSD simply for a backup, but fortunately many applications like Clonezilla can intelligently only backup the valuable data.

However as I learned the C: drive is BitLocker encrypted. That's a problem, because this way Clonezilla or similar backup solutions see only random noise and cannot compress the data, they revert back to `dd`. Not feasible for me.

In various forums and tech websites I've read that Windows 11 Home does not offer BitLocker encryption: I know now that this is not true in all cases. These websites are right in one thing though: the commonly suggested techniques to decrypt the drive are just missing, such as:

- In the Control Panel I don't have the "BitLocker Drive Encryption" option (Technique 1 in https://thecategorizer.com/windows/disable-bitlocker-windows-11/) [image]
- If I right click on the "This PC", I don't have a "Manage BitLocker" option either (Technique 3 in https://thecategorizer.com/windows/disable-bitlocker-windows-11/) [image]

Now as for the rest of the options in that URL: fortunately some decades of experience suggests to me that I won't simply fiddle with the registry or yank out services, because I'd just shoot myself in the foot that way: the decryption process needs to happen and it's just not enough to simply yeet the related services.

So this is where I'm now. My Windows 11 Home does indeed have BitLocker capability and I want to decrypt before the backup. The restore procedure would be the reverse: restore everything from the Clonezilla image and then enable BitLocker.

---

Seems like people don't believe that Windows 11 Home does BitLocker. Maybe this BitLocker is not the same BitLocker as other BitLockers? It is sure as hell encrypted though! Here are some screenshots:

1. What happens if you try to boot a BitLocker encrypted OS without Secure boot on? (this happens sometimes now that I try to boot various rescue, backup and live USB sticks, and I may forget to turn it back on): [image]
2. Here is msinfo32: [image]
3. Aaand the Disk Management screenshot: [image]

Now on that Disk Management screenshot you can see what's my workaround solution: I shrank the partition. This way I will be able to back it up to a 128 GB medium even if it's encrypted. It's kinda stunning that the system takes up 72GB after fresh install, and I didn't even mention the 15.6GB recovery partition and so on, it adds up. Anyway, I hope with these screenshots I can prove my initial setup.

Comment: BitLocker isn’t a feature of Windows 11 Home. The reason those options don’t exist on your installation is because your driver isn’t encrypted with BitLocker. The only way to encrypt a system drive on Windows 11 Home is with [Windows Device Encryption](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-encryption-in-windows-ad5dcf4b-dbe0-2331-228f-7925c2a3012d). BitLocker not being a feature of Windows 11 Home is an absolute fact

Comment: @Ramhound I was not using any pen drives or anything, this was an OEM Windows pre-install and then a finished install. It did this out of the box. Unfortunately there's already a Linux plowed over it. I remember seeing a "Device encryption" or something like that. The encryption was performed with the help of TPM.

Comment: Device Encryption and BitLocker are not the same feature.  I am confused, do you currently have this problem, or is this a problem you previously had and are no longer able to get information on.  In order to answer what is going on, knowing what protectors the system is using, is vital knowledge.  I asked 3 days ago, if you were using Device Encryption, and linked you to a Microsoft page and explained how to determine if you were using Device Encryption.  I have no idea why you are bringing up "pen drives" what does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 1):

[This page neatly lists the steps](https://pureinfotech.com/enable-bitlocker-device-encryption-windows-11-home/) to disable "BitLocker" on Windows 11 Home:

> 1. Open Settings.
> 2. Click on Privacy & security.
> 3. Under the “Security” section, click the Device encryption page.
> 4. Turn off Device encryption to disable BitLocker on Windows 11 Home.
> 5. Click the Turn off button.

The BitLocker on Windows 11 Home (titled "Device encryption") appears to be something else than the  BitLocker on Windows 11 Pro, but that's besides the point.

Comment: No clue, I'm fine with calling it all "encryption", this is my first hit on Startpage:https://www.thewindowsclub.com/difference-between-device-encryption-and-bitlocker

Comment: @CsabaToth - I told you 3 days ago it wasn't BitLocker.  Device Encryption and BitLocker are **NOT** the same feature.  One exists on Windows 10 Home and Professional and the other only exists on Windows 10 Professional.  Device Encryption is enabled per requirements determined by Microsoft on any device that is considered a Tablet.  Listing out the BitLocker protectors (i.e. none) would have given me the information, required to answer your question, 3 days ago.

Comment: Ah ok, so when device encryption is enabled on Windows Home it's normally not the case that Bitlocker is mentioned in device management? The naming of these two functions [seems to be a source of confusion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/536b1613-22e6-4190-9b9a-d159b536146d/bitlocker-device-encryption-vs-device-encryption?forum=win10itprosecurity). I agree that the OP did not provide you with all the necessary information, but I also think that holding onto "Windows 11 Home does not have Bitlocker" didn't help either, and might have made it more difficult to get that info.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound I already nuked the installation, didn't have time to fiddle with it more unfortunately, I need to progress with the installation over it.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Wasn't me, but maybe it needs *6. Wait for the drive to be decrypted.*

Comment: @CsabaToth - If you still had the installation and went to *Privacy & Security -> Device Encryption* there would have been a toggle to enable or in your case disable “device encryption”. Fundamentally, Device Encryption and BitLocker are very similar, Device Encryption was made mandatory, for an OEM to sell a mobile Tablet device with Windows 10 on it. How you disable BitLocker is slightly different, which is done through the Control Panel, Settings (Disk & volumes), or using the BitLocker manager tool to disable (not suspending BitLocker protection) on a disk.

Comment: For what is worth, I don't see the option to turn off device encryption in the corresponding tab of the control panel.