# Bitlocker error in Windows 10 home Using shrink volume

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, encryption

This post is similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1155078/bitlocker-partition-shrinking-problems), but there are some important differences  that make this a different scenario.

I have a PC running windows 10 home that I'm trying to partition the drive of. I need to shrink the volume, but it throws the error below.

> BitLocker Drive Encryption cannot be used because critical BitLocker system files are missing or corrupted. Use Windows Startup Repair to restore these files to your computer.

Now, the difference between my issue and the post above is that my drives are in **no way** encrypted with bitlocker.

I also do not have bitlocker installed as expected.

I ran a couple codes from the original post to turn off bitlocker from powershell and naturally it threw an error saying my drives aren't encrypted.

I've rebooted multiple times and it still throws the error. Does anyone have any idea what I should do here?

Here are some screenshots for reference:
[Disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8465.png),
[and as requested, the settings menu with a missing "device encryption" menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXYse.png)

*On a footnote: I ran a batch script from major geeks that enables the group policy editor in windows 10 home. I'm not sure if that has any association, but it doesn't hurt to mention just in case.*

Comment: BitLocker CANNOT be enabled on Windows 10 Home.  It is literally impossible.  What you have enabled is called **Device Encryption**.  BitLocker and Device Encryption are NOT the same feature.  If you are getting that particular error, on Windows 10 Home, it means your drive is encrypted with Device Encryption.  Device Encryption is a mandatory feature, that must be enabled, on specific types of OEM devices.  In particular any device that is a Tablet, that comes with Windows 10+, must not only support Device Encryption but come with it enabled by default.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1738121/how-to-decrypt-the-system-drive-and-disable-bitlocker-in-windows-11-home/1738535?noredirect=1#comment2693906_1738535) question has an explanation, of how to disable Device Encryption, or at the very least will allow you to provide the necessary information required to answer your question.  My previous commentary is only informative by the way.

Comment: Provide a screenshot of `Disk Management` and `Settings -> Update & Security > Device encryption` and update your question

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your `Settings -> Update & Security > Device` screenshot doesn't show the relevant information within that particular section.  I was looking for the device encryption status within that particular page within Settings.

Comment: I assume the error code is 0x8031004A?

Comment: I can't provide that. As you can see in the screenshot, it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: I completely forgot about an error code. Running `manage-bde -off C:` I get code `0x80070057`

Comment: I am interested in the error code associated with the error you received in an error dialog.

Comment: There wasn't any, or I would've typed it out. What I typed out is exactly, word for word, everything the error had to say.

Comment: Ok, so update, I tried to run a backup and got the same error. I have an error code this time around. As you predicted @Ramhound the error code is 0x8031004A.